# css animate for new learner, why fadeOut div back when end of the animate

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I'm learning `css animate`, and use `animate.css` to run a simple demo, but what I'm confused about is why the `fadeOut` div shows up again when animate finished.

you can see my demo http://plnkr.co/edit/PpfweRh9xCzfzraep4ex

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want it to show again, add this line after animation:

```
var container = document.getElementById('yourID'); //yourID is the id of the div you want to fade
container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: i want to fadeout and never back

Answer (score 0):

Because animate.css have @keyframes  , when @keyframe finish the style apply for this anitmation finished

looks like it does animate.css :   jsfiddle.net/qATqn/

if you want the style keep look this : jsfiddle.net/V2gVe/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the destination state for the animation on your element. So if you want it to fade out, you'd need to add `opacity: 0` for the fadeOut to stick once it has completed.